# Zend framework Undefined class constant '' in Zend/Db/Select.php

Tags: database, zend-framework, fatal-error, class-constants, isnullorempty

There is a srange error in my Apache Log :

PHP Fatal error: Undefined class constant ''

This is on line 814 of de library (Zend framework 1.11) library/Zend/Db/Select.php

A look of the code :

> `if ($type == self::FROM) {
>
>         // append this from after the last from joinType
>
>        $tmpFromParts = $this->_parts[self::FROM];
>
>        $this->_parts[self::FROM] = array();
>
>        // move all the froms onto the stack
>
>        while ($tmpFromParts) {
>
>            $currentCorrelationName = key($tmpFromParts);
>
>            if ($tmpFromParts[$currentCorrelationName]['joinType'] != self::FROM) {
>
>                           break;
>
>            }
>
>            $lastFromCorrelationName = $currentCorrelationName;
>
>            $this->_parts[self::FROM][$currentCorrelationName] = array_shift($tmpFromParts);
>
>       }     }`

That's strange because the undefined constant is empty.
THis fatal error appears some times but not at every load of pages.
Is it a release BUG of the zend framework?

Comment: const FROM = 'from'; check this is ite defined on top ??

Comment: I  am using same library from last 4 projects never got this problem ??

Comment: compare with source, maybe an developer from hell has changed the framework ;) https://github.com/christophervalles/Zend-Framework-Skeleton/blob/master/library/Zend/Db/Select.php

Comment: is this error associated with a specific query? It looks as though the error is caused when the '*from*' in a query is not correct. Like the tablename is _wrong/not present_, column name _wrong/not present_ or a DbTable model has bad information